# Problems passing json to javascript in flask application

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I have the following route code:

```
@app.route('/getUser', methods=['GET'])
def getUser():
    main = Main()
    value = request.args.get('user_name')
    user = main.getValues(value)
    print(json.dumps(user))
    return json.dumps(user)
```

which passes json to the template:

```
<form>
        <label>Nome usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="user_name" id="user_name"/>
        <button id="btn_pesquisar">Pesquisar</button> <br>

        <label id="id"></label> <br>
        <label id="nome"></label>

    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8">
        $('#btn_pesquisar').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get("/getUser", { user_name: $('#user_name').val() })
            .done(function( data ) {
                $('#id').html("Id: " + data.id) +
                $('#nome').html("Nome: " + data.nome)
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but when I ask for the javascript to put the json values ​​in the label, it puts `undefined`, however when I print the json before the return in the route function it returns the following json:
`{"id": 17, "nome": "teste", "idade": 22, "senha": "1234"}`

Can anyone help me put the values in the template?

Comment: You might need to tell jQuery that the response is in JSON format, it's probably being interpreted as a string.

Comment: Its works, I change json.dumps(user) for jsonify(user), thans for help

Answer (score 0):

In python, `json.dumps` will produce a string.

You need `JSON.parse(your_string)` which will produce an object that you can then access with jQuery.